# Google Refine Regular expression

Tags: regex, openrefine

I'm trying to use a regular expression (GREL) to delete strings in a cell that not start with a specific character (es "@").

Example

I'd like to transform this:

**@user1 write something to @user2 and say hello**

to:

**@user1 @user2**

Thanks a lot 
AZ

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `(?<!\S)[^@]\S*` with empty string.